# springboot org.apache.jasper.JasperException Attribute invalid for tag according to TLD

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-boot

I have been trying to migrate my existing Spring MVC project to Springboot everything went well except **org.apache.jasper.JasperException** exception for some jsp which was working fine earlier
here is code and exception

```
<form:input cssClass="form-control" id="serviceURL"
                                                    path="serviceURL" maxlength="250" value='${serviceProviderData.serviceURL}'
                                                    oninput="this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();"
                                                    onblur="this.value=this.value.trim();return validateserviceURL();"
                                                    onclick="clearErrorMsg('serviceURLErrDiv');" />
```

for this I'm getting **Attribute [value] invalid for tag [input] according to TLD**
Here is tag which i have included in jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
```

Exception logs

```
2017-11-07 14:49:24.941 ERROR 6911 --- [nio-8092-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/web] threw exception [/WEB-INF/pages/service.jsp (line: [168], column: [13]) Attribute [value] invalid for tag [input] according to TLD] with root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/service.jsp (line: [168], column: [13]) Attribute [value] invalid for tag [input] according to TLD
```

dependency for jsp rendering

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
```

I don't have any idea where I'm doing wrong because **same jsp was fine earlier with Spring MVC**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete .tld file from WEB-INF location.

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute like `oninput` for a `form:input` tag. See the complete list of valid form:input attributes [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/InputTag.html)

Comment: i have only one question why it was working earlier with spring MVC but not working in springboot is there any way i can ignore these attribute checker ?

Comment: I don't think so. from the code that you have written, you can use `onkeypress` attribute of `form:input`, so that you to make the value to lower case every time the key is pressed. Or you can stick to plain html input box as `<input type="text" oninput="myFunction()">`

Answer (score 0):

According to the spring [FORM TLD documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-form.tld), there is no oninput definition

```
I think you was using <form input=".." > as part of html not <form:input > as taglib.
```